# How to insert hyperlink into email body

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, outlook

I created a macro in Excel to send emails to various users every time a specific file is updated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim answer As String

answer = MsgBox("Would you like to save the changes?", vbYesNo, "Save Document")

If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True

If answer = vbYes Then
    'open outlook type stuff
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    'add recipients
    'newmsg.Recipients.Add ("Name1")
    newmsg.Recipients.Add ("email@xxx.com")
    'newmsg.Recipients.Add ("Name2")
    newmsg.Recipients.Add ("email@xxx.com")
    'add subject
    newmsg.Subject = "Notification - Update file"
    'add body
    newmsg.Body = "This is an automated notification." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "The XXX file has been recently updated" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Please do not reply to this email."
    newmsg.Display 'display
    newmsg.Send 'send message
    'give conformation of sent message
    MsgBox "Your document has successfully been saved", , "Confirmation"
End If

'save the document
'Me.Worksheets.Save

End Sub
```

I would like to add a hyperlink to the body text where it says "The **XXX file** has been recently updated" so that **XXX file** is a clickable link to a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the HTMLBody property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Note, the [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-bodyformat-property-outlook) property allows you to programmatically change the editor that is used for the body of an item.

The last two supports creating a hyperlink in the message body. It is up to you which way is to choose.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Eugene. I'm just starting with vba codes so it's always good to get such clarifications to understand the logic.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that, you'll have to write HTML instead of plain text. 
This line:

```
newmsg.Body = "The XXX file has been recently updated"
```

... would become something like:

```
newMsg.HTMLBody = "The <a href=" & """" & "http://www.yourlink.com" & """" & ">XXX file</a> has been recently updated".
```

This is because in Outlook emails with formatting you write HTML text, and a link in HTML is expressed as follows:

```
<a href="yourlink">your Hyper-text</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your indications and I got what I wanted.

Comment: @IdCB in that case, please accept the answer so that the thread will be closed